# UITableView in ScrollView - how to change scroll handler?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a pretty weird setup due to time restrictions and UI requirements.

The layout is pretty simple: the root view is a ScrollView, with a StackView in it. StackView has two elements, a header (which I wish to collapse), and the content (which is a custom tab bar, and below that, a container view for the tab bar's linked content).

Latter is constrained in height to the ScrollView, resulting in a kind of "sticky header" (the tab bar's top sticks to the navigation bar's bottom) and "collapsing header" (the header view is "collapsed", as it is scrolled out of the view).

This works fine, however I can't seem to find any information regarding how to handle scroll events. What I want is a "single" scrollable view with the tab bar being sticky.

The end result would work like this:

User starts scrolling, ScrollView handles scrolling up until the moment it "bottoms out", then hands over scrolling to the UITableView currently visible. When the user starts scrolling up, the UITableView currently visible scrolls until it hits the top, and immediately hands over scrolling to the outer ScrollView, which will then scroll down the tab bar and reveal the header.

On Android it's quite simple to implement, due to the Toolbar component's extendibility, but on iOS I'm dead in the water how to implement this. I've tried looking up scroll handover, but haven't found anything related to my issue - possibly I've used the wrong search query, but not sure.

How could I hand over the scroll event the easiest way?

Comment: Hard to understand your issue can you share the project?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share it. Let me try to explain: I have a header (an imageview), a tab bar, and a contentview below said tab bar. In the content view I have a tableview. The tabbar and contentview are in a single container that is the same size as the root view, and all of this is in a scrollview - this way when one scrolls, the fixed view size results in the tab bar sticking just under the navigationbar. But the scroll gesture is not handed over to the tableview when the scrollview reaches the end, so the user needs to scroll twice - once the scrollview, then the tableview.

Comment: I want to be able to scroll the whole shebang with a single scroll gesture, and depending on the current state (tableview scroll position and outer scrollview position), I want to transfer the handling of the scroll gesture to the appropriate element.

Comment: I think you need to play with either tableview or scrollview only one at once. It's not possible to achieve using both. Of course in your case firstly scrollview will scroll & then tableview. Just check that ... is it possible to achieve that using only tableview & add top contents in the tableview header.